# Google OAuth Token Force Expiration Not Happening

Tags: oauth, google-api

I was forcibly trying to expire the Google API OAuth Access Token for the Contacts API.

Here is the general outline of my test:

Get the code:

```
auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()    
redirect(auth_uri) code here
```

Exchange it for the access token:

```
code = request.GET.get('code')
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
store_for_reuse(key, credentials)
store_for_refresh(key, credentials)
```

Get a new access token:

```
credentials_original = get_for_reuse(key)
credentials_for_refresh = get_for_refresh(key)
credentials_for_refresh.refresh(http)
```

Now, I can verify that the two credentials object have different access token values

```
credentials_original.access_token != credentials_for_refresh.acesss_token
```

Surprisingly, I can still make successful API calls with the original access token. Shouldn't the original one expire when the new access token is issued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a new token does not expire existing tokens. Tokens will be valid for their designated lifespan unless [explicitly revoked](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke).

Comment: Got it. Doesn't this expose a potential risk, though?

Comment: Tokens are only valid for an hour by default so any risk is short lived. Plus if an attacker manages to get the original token it's likely they can get the new token as well.